# How can I renew my Italian passport abroad?

Tags: international-travel, passports, paperwork, consulates, italian-citizens

I'm Italian, I'm living between China and India and my passport is going to expire in June 2014.

Right now I'm in China and this is my trip plan:

- in Sept. I will go India
- in October I will be back in China
- in April I will go to India again
- in May I will come to China again

The issue is that in April/May my passport will have less that 6 month of validity and to have a new Visa for India/China it is required that the passport has a validity of at least 6 month.

Take care that **my passport has already 10 years** so I cannot just apply some stamps on it but I need to do a complete new one.

As you can imagine I would like to not coming back to Italy only to renew my passport (it is a kind of expensive and no sense).

1. Is it possible to renew the passport abroad? (also if it is not completely expired?)
2. If yes, How can I do it? I need to go to the Italian Embassy in China?
3. What kind of documents could be required?

Comment: Aside from the renewal, watch out for common visa/entry regulations that require a passport with *no less than x (usually 6) months validity remaining*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can, from the official site of [Italian Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.esteri.it/MAE/Templates/GenericTemplate.aspx?NRMODE=Published&NRNODEGUID=%7bA3B1B351-A44D-4196-9222-625895EC0D0F%7d&NRORIGINALURL=%2fMAE%2fEN%2fMinistero%2fServizi%2fSportello_Info%2fDomandeFrequenti%2fUfficiServiziConsolariEstero%2fPassaporti%2ehtm&NRCACHEHINT=Guest#6):

> **Is it possible to apply for or renew my Italian passport at a consulate where I am not a resident?**
>   Yes, but in that case it is necessary to obtain a clearance (nulla osta) from:
>   the police (Questura) where you are a resident  for citizens residing in Italy, and
>   authorised consulate for citizens residing in other consular jurisdictions.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, the Republic of Italy still abides by jus sanguinis, which means that citizenship is passed down by descendent, regardless of where the individual was born or what their current connection with Italy is - so long as their parent is a citizen too.

As there is no limit to this, it means that the Italian state has to provide its diaspora with places to apply and have their passports renewed, like every state with a large diaspora community (Ireland, for example).

As a result, you should be able to renew your passport at any embassy or consulate which is associated with Italy. I would call (or email) the embassy in the country where you think you will be staying and they will be able to to advise you further.